# Unable to create a new item from SharePoint 2010 website in the local system

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint website which is running in the both server and local.

Website is running fine in the server, but when it's running in the local system I can see all the display items, but when going to create a new item on list or library I'm getting an error message like below that List doesn't exist.

[image]

The image above for creating a simple contact list by clicking on Add new item.

Is there any way to fix this issue or 
anything that I have to set permissions in the server.

Comment: Someone can please advise to resolve the problem that I'm facing right now with running SharePoint website from local..

Answer (score 0):

It was just because I didn't create an alternative access mapping with intranet option for the web application. Web application is now accessible with all functionality like what I am able do it through server.